# Can EnumDisplayDevices detect a device if it's drivers are not installed?

Tags: c++, .net, windows

I need to deploy a hard drive image to a customer which on the first boot detects the graphics card type and installs the appropriate drivers. So what this means in terms of code is that I need to detect the deviceid of the graphics card in C++ without using GPU specific libraries like NvAPI or AMD SDK.

I know that EnumDisplayDevices can retrieve deviceids, so all I need to know is whether this is possible with EnumDisplayDevices, or whether the GPUs drivers must be installed before EnumDisplayDevices can detect it. How the function actually goes about obtaining this information isn't mentioned in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article.

Thanks,

Bill.

Comment: Well, Windows will usually detect such devices and install a generic driver, so I would hazard a guess that EnumDisplayDevices will work, in most cases at least.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purposes I needed to know the name and model of the graphics card, and it turns out EnumDisplayDevices can't retrieve this information until the drivers are installed.